# Nuxt project with vuetify2 throws error for deployment

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt project and migrated 1 month ago to vuetify 2.0 from vuetify 1.5. Everything has worked perfectly for development after `yarn generate` or `yarn build`. However, when I decided to publish the project, I got errors related to sass loader after `yarn generate`.

I tested nuxt project with vuetify 2 and got different errors about sass loader.

I wonder if there is any problem, how it worked in development, and what is exactly happening in build or generate command that the errors were thrown. What should I do to resolve the issue?

I think I found the origin of the error: In nuxt-config.ts, the file that I have in

```
styleResources: {
    scss: ['@/assets/sass/variables.scss']
  },
```

includes:

```
@import 'responsiveStyle';
$bg-color: white !important;
$primary-color: #1caefa !important;
$accent-color: #6c7293 !important;
```

I get this error: https://ibb.co/H7VvRVt

If I remove @import 'responsiveStyle, this error would raise:
https://ibb.co/KVQ08S9

This is a sample project including the error after yarn-generate command: https://github.com/nargesmomenyan/nuxt-vuetify2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the @nuxtjs/style-resources module according to this issue:
https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module/issues/82

I upgraded this module to version 1.0.0 and the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

[Go to this link](https://webnation.co.jp/upgrading-to-vuetify-2-0-in-a-existing-nuxt-js-project/)

and see what you have to do to successfully migrate from 1.5 to 2,
there has been a lot of changes already.
See [here](https://dev.to/anoff/migrating-vuetify-1-5-to-2-1-249n)